# How to dynamically call routes helper in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

For example, I have constructed a string called "new_work_path", now I want to call that helper as a method.

I've tried `send("new_work_path", vars)` and calling the same send from many objects. But I don't think that I've found the right object to call these helpers.

To do `object.send("new_work_path", vars)`, what **object** should I be looking for?

I've tried to look for this online for a while but couldn't find anything. If anyone can shine some lights on this one, it would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Helper methods can only be called from within a view context, not a model if that's what you're trying to do. Can you be more specific about where you're trying to execute this? A standard `send` call should be sufficient if you have the right context.

Comment: I'm trying to execute this in the application_helper where a standard route helper call would function properly.

Comment: What's the error you're getting, then? Can you post an example? If calling `new_work_path` directly works, then `send(:new_work_path)` should be equivalent.

Comment: Wow, this time it worked. I must have missed something the first time then. Indeed send(:new_work_path) works just like that. Now I'm feeling irritated by my stupidity. Haha thanks!

Comment: How do I close a question btw?

Comment: If you can figure out what the problem was, you can always post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

try `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send(...)`

Edit:

As Larry Gebhardt [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596168/how-to-dynamically-call-routes-helper-in-rails/19190826?noredirect=1#comment99528433_19190826) the `url_helpers` module is no longer being cached.

Another workaround would be:

```
cached_helpers = Class.new do
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include Rails.application.routes.mounted_helpers
end.new

cached_helpers.send(...)
```

Comment: Works well. Deserves "best answer" :)

Comment: This works well. Let's say you want to link to a nested resource, you could write `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send("new_#{@model.class.name.downcase}_comment_url", "#{@model.class.name.downcase}_id".to_sym => @model)`, since you need a parent `model_id`.

Comment: If you are trying to access `url_helpers` from a mounted `Rails::Engine`, try `"<EngineName>::Engine".constantize.routes.url_helpers.send(...)' where `<EngineName>` is from the `mount` line in your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: I believe this answer should no longer be considered valid. Rails is no longer caching the anonymous module returned by `url_helpers`. This could result in a large number of modules containing the helper methods being generated. See https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/07dfd2ea097706ef0240f1dda5236cdc5f2c8843.

Comment: Seems like caching of url_helpers [was brought back](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/37e778b6b44ae087ce052ff380b1e3aaee31473d#diff-8cb3fb539a8c272b689394a45bc55877071bc4d01a3b4dc69a9c54c7ae6499aa) in rails 6.1

Answer (score 11):

My bad, as per @tadman suggested, I tried to use `send(:new_work_path, args)` again and it worked! Must have mistyped it before.

Before finding out that send works right away, I had found another solution which is also of interest:

```
new_polymorphic_path(Work, args)
```

Which seems to offer some syntactic sugar as well.

Comment: polymorphic_path is fun, you can also do `polymorphic_path(:foo)` or `polymorphic_path("bar")`

Answer (score 0):

My two cents to the accepted answer.
Please always keep in mind that `send` [is a risky command](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/security_rdoc.html#label-send) that you should avoid if possible, or at least having a white list of available options to be accepted by your `send` call. In case you don't want to use it, Rails have [its own way](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html) to get paths dynamically with `.url_for`:

```
[5] pry(main)> include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
=> Object
[6] pry(main)> url_for(controller: 'one_path/the_controller', action: 'valid_path')
=> "http://localhost:3000/one_path/the_controller/valid_path"
[7] pry(main)> url_for(controller: 'one_path/the_controller', action: 'some_h4cky_thing')
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"some_h4cky_thing", :controller=>"one_path/the_controller"}
```

also `.link_to` has its own built-in option for this purpose:

```
<%= link_to "A link to #{option}", {controller: 'one_path/the_controller', action: option}, target: '_blank' %>
```